# mime type of uploading file is application/octet-stream fails

Tags: laravel-5, file-upload

I have a form for uploading pdf document and am using laravel validation in my controller like,

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
       'document' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,pdf|max:25600',
]);
```

some of the images and pdf documents mime types like **application/octet-stream**

is there any way to check that application/octet-stream file mime is png, jpeg or pdf file ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've got the same problem, it wasn't a Laravel issue.

I fixed this modifying

php.ini

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 10M ; from 5M to 10M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 10M  ; from 5M to 10M
```

Comment: Don't forget to restart php-fpm.